# Architecture: API with slightly different behavior depending on the logged-in user roles

Tags: architecture, api, source-code

How should I structure a piece of code that executes an operation, but may have slightly different behavior depending on, let's say, user roles?

Example:
My app has a 'manager' and a 'employee' roles. There are many managers in my app, and each of them have many employees. I have a dashboard where managers and their employees can add/edit/delete products.

Both can edit the products the have created themselves, but managers can edit products belonging to his employees. If a manager edits a product created by an employee, the employee will get an email notification about the edit.

The issue I have, is that I´m creating if/else or switch/case statements for checking the user roles, and I feel once I add new roles my code will need to check for them too and my code will become harder to read.

For example:

```
// What I currently have:
public function updateProductForUser(Product $product, UserInterface $user)
{
    $userWhoCreatedProduct = $product->getCreatedByUser();

    if ($userWhoCreatedProduct === $user) {
        // If the user who created the product is the same one trying to update it,
        // then go ahead and execute the update.
        $this->_doUpdateProductForUser($product, $user);
        return;

    } elseif ($user instanceof Manager) {
        $allManagerEmployees = $this->someService->findAllEmployeesOfManager($user);

        if (in_array($userWhoCreatedProduct, $allManagerEmployees)) {
            // If the user trying to update the product is a manager, and the product was
            // created by an employee of the manager, then execute the update but also
            // send an notification to the employee that the product he created got updated
            // by his manager.
            $this->_doUpdateProductForUser($product, $user);
            $this->notifyUserThatProductGotUpdated($product);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I improve this? Is there a better way? What are the pitfalls of the implementation? Any advice is very welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Please explain with words, not code.

Comment: Are you asking about architecture or source code. The latter is better for stack overflow and is off-topic here; architecture might be on topic.

Comment: @Tibo, Tom Au. Many thanks for responding. I´ve removed most of the code and left the important bits. My question is about architecture and avoid my code from getting messier. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the code a little more maintainable if you

- Put the product handling logic (without permission logic and without other side effects) into a separate service class ProductDomain. (See [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) for details)
- Create a ProductHandlingService class that uses ProductDomain and applies permissions and other side effects
- give the conditions a name (See [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for details)

The ProductHandlingService  might look like this:

```
public function updateProductForUser(Product $product, UserInterface $userWhoWantsToModify)
{
  if ($strategy->userIsAllowedToModifyProduct($product, $userWhoWantsToModify) {
    $ProductDomain->_doUpdateProductForUser($product, $userWhoWantsToModify);
    if ($strategy->userNeedsInfoAboutProductUpdate($product, $product->getCreatedByUser(),
          $userWhoWantsToModify) {
      $this->notifyUserThatProductGotUpdated($product);
    }
  }
}
```

Advantages over the original design:

- core-ProductDomain, Permission-detection and special-handling can be tested independently.
- During software lifetime it is likely that Permission-detection and special-handling will be change often due to political reasons.
- core-ProductDomain is likely to change not very often and mostly because of technical reasons.